# Correct expression for photon 4-momentum

Tags: general-relativity, kinematics, photons, momentum, velocity

Using that the photon is on a null geodesic, we can write the geodesic equation: 
$$g^{\mu\nu}\dot{x}_\mu\dot{x}_\nu = 0,$$
and probably also $$g^{\mu\nu}{p}_\mu{p}_\nu = 0$$.

My question: in [this](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~chirata/ph217/lec02.pdf) resource, they claim in Eq. (1) that $$p^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu}{ds} \tag{1},$$
where $s$ is an affine parameter $\neq$ proper time. Is the above definition of photon 4-momentum correct? Since the photon follows null paths I have previously understood that there is no good way of defining its 4-velocity, which is normally written as $dx^\mu/ds$.

Comment: Usually the photon 4-momentum is defined as $p^{\mu} \rightarrow (E,0,0,0)$ - this statement is false in SR, where this vector is timelike (and thus can't be associated to photon's 4-momentum). In GR this statement doesn't make sense unless you specify the coordinate system (e.g. by giving the expression for $g_{\mu \nu}$). The last equation is only valid for massive particles.

Comment: Edited, you are right! This was exactly my question, is this relation correct? I have seen it in other places too, which is why I am confused

Comment: Yes, $-g_{\mu \nu} p^{\mu} p^{\nu} = m^2 = 0$.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @gj255: the photon momentum is not arbitrary as its contraction with the 4-velocity of an observer has to yield its energy in that particular frame

Comment: @Christoph You're right, thanks. Let me change my comment.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{d}x^\mu/\mathrm{d}s$ is a tangent vector to the curve $x^\mu(s)$. For any particle, the 4-velocity is tangent to the particle's worldline. For massive particles, we can scale this tangent vector so that it has unit length and call it the 4-velocity, or scale it so that it has length $m$ and call it the 4-momentum. For photons the tangent will always have 'length' zero, so we cannot 'normalise' it. Nevertheless, we often say that $\mathrm{d}x^\mu/\mathrm{d}s$ represents the 4-velocity of the photon, and acknowledge that there was arbitrariness in this choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any solution to the geodesic equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^{2}x^{\mu}}{\mathrm ds^{2}}+\Gamma_{\rho\sigma}^{\mu}\frac{\mathrm dx^{\rho}}{\mathrm ds}\frac{\mathrm dx^{\sigma}}{\mathrm ds}=0.
$$
will be affinely parametrized. This parametrization is only unique up to transformations $s' = a\cdot s + b$, each of which yields a different magnitude of the tangent vector $\mathrm dx^\mu / \mathrm ds$. This magnitude will remain constant along the curve as we're dealing with a metric connection.

For time-like geodesic, two of these tangent vectors (or more precisely, vector fields along the curve) are of particular interest, the so-called 4-velocity normalized to unity, and the momentum vector, whose contraction with the 4-velocity yields the particle's energy in its rest frame (aka its mass).

For light-like geodesics, there's no way to uniquely define its 4-velocity as all possible choices have the same magnitude 0, which also precludes the definition of a rest energy. However, we can still single out a momentum vector, namely the one that yields the correct energy in another frame (eg the photon energy in the frame of emitter or absorber).

As to your question, personally I would not understand the relation
$$
p^\mu = \frac{\mathrm dx^\mu}{\mathrm ds}
$$
as the definition of momentum, but rather the defintion of a certain affine parametrization $s$ compatible with the momentum.

Comment: Thanks for this. As for your last remark, does that mean that I can use the last relation to represent the momentum? Moreover, that would enable me to write (with $\lambda$ as the affine parameter and $p^0 = E$): $\frac{d}{d\lambda} = \frac{dx^0}{d\lambda} \frac{d}{dx_0} = p^0 \frac{d}{dt}$. Is that right?

Comment: @koldrakan: yes, and the lecture notes make use of this, cf eq (11) and (12)